# R memory full right at the start of installation

Tags: r, memory

[Rstudio Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIWEp.png)

Hi, I'm at the beginning of learning R. When I downloaded this R desktop, the memory tab in the Environment section showed it's almost full even though I've never uploaded any data yet. They just automatically appeared in the Plot section. Is there a way to remove all the files to get the full memory?
Any advice would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really mean `... automatically appeared in the Plot section` or is this a typo and do you mean `automatically appeared in the "Files" section` in your screenshot?

Comment: Sorry yes the Files section